# When viewing a product node, how to show/ enable the original node title?

Tags: nodes

I am using commerce in my drupal site, but the node title is not there. Debugging it in the `page.tpl.php` returns an empty string `''`. I know you can enable the title in the display settings of the content type and product variation, but this is rather a field within the node article, that has no influence of the title not being shown within the page template.

Obviously, the title is being set to `''` somehow, but I cant figure out where this happens or, even more importantly, how to change this with my custom module.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that within the `commerce_kickstart_product_ui_preprocess_page` function the node title of product nodes is being set to `''`, for what reason ever. I wrote a custom module with weight higher than 50 and re-enabled the title:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // make the title display available again
  $product_display_types = commerce_product_reference_node_types();
  if (isset($vars['node']->type) && isset($product_display_types[$vars['node']->type])) {
    $vars['title'] = $vars['node']->title;
  }
}
```